# Can you add an "undo" step in an action in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, actions

I'm trying to make an action that will:

- Crop the left half of the image
- Save as a PDF
- Undo the crop
- Crop the right half of the image
- Save as a PDF
- Undo the crop
- Go up one layer
- Repeat for all layers

I'm just not sure you can "undo" the crop. Googling only leads me to a million tutorials on how to undo a whole action etc...

If there's another way to do what I'm trying to accomplish, I'm definitely open to new ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. But it's not *technically* "Undo". It's a step back in history.

Start your action recording and use `Edit > Step Backwards` after a save.... it should record that.

The actual "Undo" menu item won't work and will be disabled.

Comment: This works, thanks. I was also able to do it by manually selecting the previous state in the History panel!

Comment: @jemtan990 The history panel was key! Thanks. This was driving me nuts.